# Post-increment in assignment to reference c++

Tags: c++, reference, post-increment

Assume I have this code:

```
int i = 2;
int &ref = i++;
```

Now, I understand that reference can not be initiaizied with rvalue, 
but I can not understand why `ref` isn't initialized with lvalue, meaning here, `i`, and after that `i` incremented.

Moreover, in the following case:

```
   int i = 2;
   const int &ref = i++;
   cout << ref << endl;
```

`2` will be printed, and it means that `ref` initialized with `i` before increment, i.e. initialized with lval. 
After that `ref` is incremented, but `ref` is const.

Can someone explain me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Post-incrementing an `int` does not result in an lvalue. A hypothetical implementation might look like this:

```
int operator++(int& i) {
    int temp = i;
    ++i;
    return temp;
}
```

As you can see, a copy needs to be made and that is returned by value.

Pre-increment does result in an lvalue because no copy is required, so the result is a reference to the original.

Your second example works because rvalues can bind to references-to-const.

Comment: Cool! I should thoungt about impelementation of this operator, you right! thanks!

Comment: As Tartan wrote `i++` does not return an lvalue. As an addition from the C++ standard: `5.2.6 Increment and decrement [...] The result is a prvalue. [...]`. Also check the explanation (here)[http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization] what happens when a const-ref is initialized with a `prvalue`

Answer (score 2):

`i++` doesn't return `i`, but a temporary copy, that was taken before i got incremented. 
That's why it is called POST increment, because it increments thew variable AFTER it retained a copy of the current state.

Comment: usually it increments before returning, e.g. look at TartanLlama's implementation. The key point is that the old value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Post incrementing an int does not return in lvalue. i++ returns a temporary copy before incrementing itself.