# int &b = ++a; // this line works fine int &c = a++; // results in error

Tags: c++, reference

```
int main()
{
  int a = 10;
  int &b = ++a; // this line works fine
  int &c = a++; // results in error
}
```

can someone please explain me reason for this

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560823/post-increment-in-assignment-to-reference-c)

Comment: Read the difference between lvalue and rvalue.

Comment: use `int&& c = a++;` . You must match lvalue reference to lvalue expressions etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
int &c = a++;
```

You get the error because `a++` results in `rvalue` expression whose reference you cannot take.

[For more info on lvalue,rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Answer (score 0):

In non-technical terms, it is forbidden, to take a (non-const) reference to a temporary.

The expression `++a` does not generate a temporary. It modifies itself and returns a reference to itself.

The expression `a++` on the other hand, creates a copy of itself, then modifies itself, then returns the copy. That copy is a temporary.